# Calculating the rolling change between a column

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two columns and i am trying to get the (last value) /( "last" value of 15 mins ago). I have worked with finding difference which is quite easy but not sure how to roll over 15minutes and get its difference.

so i tried something like this

```
df['pct'] = df['Last'].rolling('15min', min_periods=15) - df['Last'] / df['Last']
```

For example:

```
(3090-3071.56) /(3071.56) =0.0060034
```

But i end up in getting error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Rolling' and 'float'
```

Columns I have

```
Timestamp        Last          
1/20/19 12:15    3071.56
1/20/19 12:17    3097.82
1/20/19 12:17    3097.82
1/20/19 12:18    3095.25
1/20/19 12:19    3087.42
1/20/19 12:20    3095.29
1/20/19 12:21    3095.25
1/20/19 12:22    3093.11
1/20/19 12:23    3103
1/20/19 12:24    3095
1/20/19 12:25    3100.6
1/20/19 12:26    3099.84
1/20/19 12:27    3098.77
1/20/19 12:29    3097.24
1/20/19 12:29    3090
1/20/19 12:30    3090
1/20/19 12:31    3094.2
```

Expected column pct:

```
                        Last     pct
Timestamp                           
2019-01-20 12:15:00  3071.56    
2019-01-20 12:17:00  3097.82     NaN
2019-01-20 12:17:00  3097.82     NaN
2019-01-20 12:18:00  3095.25     NaN
2019-01-20 12:19:00  3087.42     NaN
2019-01-20 12:20:00  3095.29     NaN
2019-01-20 12:21:00  3095.25     NaN
2019-01-20 12:22:00  3093.11     NaN
2019-01-20 12:23:00  3103.00     NaN
2019-01-20 12:24:00  3095.00     NaN
2019-01-20 12:25:00  3100.60     NaN
2019-01-20 12:26:00  3099.84     NaN
2019-01-20 12:27:00  3098.77     NaN
2019-01-20 12:29:00  3097.24     NaN
2019-01-20 12:29:00  3090.00   0.006003464
2019-01-20 12:30:00  3090.00  -0.002524356
2019-01-20 12:31:00  3094.20  -0.001139511
```

Comment: Rolling is like groupby, you have to chain a aggregation function. So in your example `df['Last'].rolling('15min', min_periods=15).mean()` if you want the rolling average.

Comment: @P.Tillmann No i am not finding a mean here, I would like to value of 15minutes - the value at the last 15minutes and then divide that with the value in the last. It should give me 0.006 and not in the range 3000. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question properly when i commented and was thrown off by your usage of rolling. What you looking for with a shift of 15 minutes (your expected pct shows 14) is:

```py
df['pct'] = (df['Last'].shift(15) - df['Last'])/df['Last']
Out[6]: 
        Timestamp     Last       pct
1/20/19     12:15  3071.56       NaN
1/20/19     12:17  3097.82       NaN
1/20/19     12:17  3097.82       NaN
1/20/19     12:18  3095.25       NaN
1/20/19     12:19  3087.42       NaN
1/20/19     12:20  3095.29       NaN
1/20/19     12:21  3095.25       NaN
1/20/19     12:22  3093.11       NaN
1/20/19     12:23  3103.00       NaN
1/20/19     12:24  3095.00       NaN
1/20/19     12:25  3100.60       NaN
1/20/19     12:26  3099.84       NaN
1/20/19     12:27  3098.77       NaN
1/20/19     12:29  3097.24       NaN
1/20/19     12:29  3090.00       NaN
1/20/19     12:30  3090.00 -0.005968
1/20/19     12:31  3094.20  0.001170
```

Please note that the behavior of numpys roll and pandas rolling is very different. Numpys roll is somewhat similar to pandas shift.

Comment: i followed the same code for one more column but it shifts me to 30minutes but the values are right. Any idea why it could be?  df['pre']= (df['Last'].shift(15)-df['Prev15minMin'].shift(15))/(df['Prev15minMax'].shift(15)-df['Prev15minMin'].shift(15))

Comment: Could you please tell me what exactly shift does? Thanks

Comment: I think the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) explains it better then i could.